# Reading dictionary file line-by-line takes strings with tons of whitespace

Tags: c, file-io, strcmp

I'm reading a dictionary file line-by-line and taking each line then comparing it with a string.  My problem is that I don't know how to dynamically allocate a length of the string on every line to remove whitespace.  I'll explain this after you see my code:

```
FILE *f;
f = fopen("/usr/share/dict/words", "r");
if (f != NULL)
{
    // maximum size of line, keep it at 128 just in case
    char line[128] = "";

    // run through every line of file
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), f))
    {
        if (strcmp("hello", line) == 0)
            printf("The string is %s!", line);
    }
}
```

So I have to initialize the "line" variable to take the maximum length of any line.  It's just that if the line is any smaller than that value of 128, it will just add whitespace to the end, resulting in an invalid comparison.  How do I change this?

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't add tons of whitespace, `fgets` leaves the newline in the buffer, though. So you have one trailing whitespace character normally. Fix it by

```
int len = strlen(line);
if (line[len-1] == '\n') {
    line[len-1] = 0;
}
```

Comment: So how should I fix this? Also, is there a better way of using the buffer?

Comment: Fix now in answer. What do you mean with "better way"? The way it is used is good.